# How to change the default from address of email send by Linux root

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail, root

I am using `sendmail` with Amazon SES. It works fine with email address which are verified only.

1. So first of all i want to know when root runs cron job then which email address it uses as from
2. How to change that email address

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the -f flag of the sendmail command to specify the envelope from address, and you should me able to specify the meesage from address in headers of the message itself.  For example:

/usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@from.com to@to.com < message.txt

Comment: but my problem is when linux cron send email then i am not able to chnage the sender email address

Comment: OK,  Try this, in your crontab:
* * * * * some_cronjob_goes_here 2>&1 | /usr/sbin/sendmail -s "message subject here" recipient@mydomain.com -f sender@mydomain.com

Comment: Or, if it's Centos6, you can just put the following in your crontab:
MAILFROM=sender@mydomain.com
MAILTO=recipient@mydomain.com